# Problems Importing Product CSV file

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I have a big issue with reading my csv file.

When I do an **export** and **open** it in **Google doc** or **Excel** the **price and qty** not show correct.
**Magento 2.2.6**

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uJ_CLLGG1WLi_udJTIEHQhx8nCLCHSTxuO-c3kw1XaM/edit?usp=sharing

Can you help me please?

Greetings Bart

Answer (score -1):

Pls show your code import product, you can try:

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); // in add new product
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); //with update product

$product->setName($row[1]);
...
$product->save();
```

and remember, update product with change in other view (Default store view):
[image]